# Mongo - new vs processed approach

Tags: mongodb, unique

I am new to Mongo and have gotten close to where I want to be after 3 days of banging my head against the keyboard, but now I think I may just be misunderstanding certain key concepts:

What I am trying to do:

I have a node script that is pulling in feed items from various sources very frequently and storing them (title, link, origin, processed:false)

I have another script pulling out records at random, one at a time, using them, and updating processed:true

End Goal: Items should be unique by title - if it's been seen before it should not be written to DB, and once it's been processed one time, it should never be processed again.

INSERT SCRIPT:

```
key = {'title':title}; 
data = {'origin':origin, 'title':title, 'original_link':original_url, 'processed':false};
collection.update(key, data, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc) { ...
```

READ SCRIPT:

```
    collection.findOne({processed:false}, function(err, doc){
            if (err) throw err; 
            logger.info("Read out the following item from mongodb:..."); 
            console.dir(doc); 
            thisId = doc._id; 
            markProcessed(thisId);

}


var markProcessed = function(id) {
        collection.update({ _id:id }, 
            {
                $set: {'processed':true},
            }, function(err, doc){
                if (err) throw err; 
                logger.info("Marked record:"+id+" as processed"); 
                console.dir(doc); 
            }

        )
};
```

I've tried using collection.ensureIndex({'title':1}, {unique:true}) to no success either.

As the two scripts run in parallel the read script ends up repeating work on already processed records, and although the markProcessed function was working all yesterday it miraculously does not today :)

I would very much appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your insert script. When you use [`collection.update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and you already have a document with the same key in the database, that document will be overwritten with the new one. An unique index doesn't prevent this, because there aren't two documents with the same title in the collection at the same time.

When you don't want to overwrite an existing record, use [`collection.insert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) which will fail when the inserted document violates an unique index.